# Facebook Like button confirm comment box broken

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I've been testing the "Like" button on a new site. After a while the normal "Like" behaviour changed to the "Confirm" behaviour (ie users are asked to click confirm to proceed), which I know is standard Facebook like-spamming prevention. This is all fine and dandy.

The issue is that after clicking confirm, the comment box appears as normal, but the Post button is broken. Nothing happens when I click it. So the total number of "likes" increases, but the post doesn't appear on the user's FB newsfeed.

On top of that, the hint text in the input field doesn't clear when I start typing into it. Is this Facebook being buggy? No problems are showing up in the Facebook Linter.

*Note:* Tested using Firefox 20.0 on Mac OSX 10.7.5

Comment: This situation also happen to me. but after removing facebook link from wordpress site.The situation is then fine.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Have you found a fix yet?